# Can I use modelsummary with vcov="robust" for cox model in R?

Tags: r, modelsummary

I have a few cox models created by `coxph`, and I want to summarise them with `modelsummary`. However, when I write `robust=T` in `coxph` script, and run `modelsummary` like below, I get an error message which says "*Error in get_vcov.default(model, vcov = vcov, conf_level = conf_level,  :
Unable to extract a variance-covariance matrix of type robust from model of class coxph. The variance-covariance matrix is required to adjust the standard errors. The `vcov` argument accepts a variance-covariance matrix, a vector of standard errors, or a function that returns one of these, such as `stats::vcov`.*"

```
modelsummary(models,
             stars=T,
             vcov = 'robust'      
)
```

Also, when I use `vcov = 'classical'`, I get the table but the stars disappear. They appear just when I write `robust=F` in my `coxph` script.

How can I use `robust=T` in `coxph` script and `vcov = 'robust'` in modelsummary together?

Comment: Try using the ‘coxrobust’ R-package

Answer (score 1):

The `modelsummary` function uses the `sandwich` package to compute robust standard errors. The `vcov="robust"` option calls `sandwich::vcovHC()` to compute heteroskedasticity-consistent standard error. It looks like this function does not support (at least some) `coxph` models.

However, some other functions from the `sandwich` package may support your model. For example, here is an example of a model where `vcovHC` does *not* work but `vcovHAC` does work (heteroskedasticity and autocorrelation-consistent standard errors).

```r
library(modelsummary)
library(survival)
library(sandwich)

bladder1 <- bladder[bladder$enum < 5, ]

mod <- coxph(
    Surv(stop, event) ~ rx + size + number,
    cluster = id,
    data = bladder1,
    robust = TRUE)

sandwich::vcovHC(mod)
#> Error in meatHC(x, type = type, omega = omega): hatvalues() could not be extracted successfully but are needed for HC3

sandwich::vcovHAC(mod)
#>                rx        size      number
#> rx     0.49295246 0.021777986 0.020566583
#> size   0.02177799 0.022118330 0.002851453
#> number 0.02056658 0.002851453 0.020215100

modelsummary(mod, vcov = "HAC", output = "markdown")
```

|  | Model 1 |
| --- | --- |
| rx | -0.540 |
|  | (0.200) |
| size | -0.055 |
|  | (0.070) |
| number | 0.193 |
|  | (0.046) |
| Num.Obs. | 340 |
| AIC | 1182.2 |
| BIC | 1193.7 |
| RMSE | 0.57 |
| Std.Errors | HAC |

Again, that may not work for all models. The key point to understand is that the model needs to be supported by `sandwich` for robust standard errors to be computed by `modelsummary`.